# Is it possbile to export IDE color settings from VS2008 into VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, settings

Question explained on title

Comment: And avoid the fun of configuring a new environment from scratch? For shame!

Comment: @shoosh agree for other options, but I spent a lot of time in setting the right colors :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the first time you install Visual Studio 2010 - it automatically does it for you. After I've finished installing the new VS opened with my color scheme from VS2008.

Comment: I uninstall VS2008 first and then installed VS2010. The nice thing is that it has restored all my previous settings :D

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Go to Tools.
Import and Export Settings
Export selected environment settings
Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors

Then import them under the same menu in 2010.
Go to Tools.
Import and Export Settings
Import selected enviroment settings